# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

I figured out some of the problems I had but I still have  "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" message for this part of the code

```
SELECT cruiseName,departuePort,shipName,TO_CHAR(price,'$99999.99') As NEWPRICE 
FROM Cruise 
WHERE Cruise.departurePort='Miami'; /* new updated prices with $ symbol and along with header NEWPRICE */
```

I  would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Also I have changed the orderby to order by but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm using OracleSQL.live

Comment: I found it online, what should I do to make them correct? This the first time I program in SQL and I'm really lost

Comment: How are you running this? The semicolon is a statement separator so it should not be there in some instances (e.g. via JDBC), and some clients let you change it. It is possible either that, or the comment, are confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I see here:

1. departurePort is misspelled in the select clause
2. remove the comment

   SELECT 
     cruiseName
     ,departurePort
     ,shipName
     ,TO_CHAR(price,'$99999.99') As NEWPRICE
   FROM Cruise
   WHERE Cruise.departurePort='Miami';

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=577ed09de69da656eac083db02833184)